# collapsable data row in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngtable

I would like to display parent and child related data in collapsable format without using panel.

**Code:**

```
<div  ng-app="app" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
     <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
         <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                 <th > {{x.Country }}</th>
                 <td >{{ x.Name }}</td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>  
</div>
```

**Preferable:**

[image]

I would like to have list of names under country and upon expanding i should be able to see list of names for that country.

Comment: Accordion come from bootstrap which is made for been responsive. As such it doesn't rely on table HTML objects.

Another way to implement this would be to use ng-if/ng-show directive and $animate for the transition.

however this won't work with table properly. Why just not add some classes to the accordion from bootstrap and override CSS defition that you don't want from panel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you using `accordion` directive  of angular-ui-bootstrap: 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

In alternative you can use the `collapse` directive inside an ng-repeat: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Adding few of the findings and development which i had to go through,

In your HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>    

<!-- custom angular script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

In your HTML for creating animation

```
<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-repeat="x in names">
                 <uib-accordion-heading >
                    {{ x.Name }} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}">
                </uib-accordion-heading>
                    {{ x.City }} </br>
                    {{ x.Country }} </br>
             </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

your app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```